# Do i need to call unregisterReceiver() during action.BOOT_COMPLETE?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm working on an Applock that locks the selected Apps, Everything is fine, i can lock the selected apps, but when the device is switched OFF, and ON again The Service is stopped, The locked apps are not locked, So i needed to use BroadCast receiver to restart the service. even though i used the broadcast still the problem not solved and i'm getting this error

```
 android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked:
  Service com.google.android.rcs.service.service.JibeService has leaked IntentReceiver 
  com.google.android.ims.network.e@d440e03 that was originally registered here. 
  Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

This is BroadCast Receiver class

```
   public class Boot_Com extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent1, 0);
            alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10000, alarmIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you have registered your broadcast receiver in manifest then if your app not running it will execute and if you mention in an activity then when your code execute at that time it will execute

```
So you need to declare it where it requires and unregisters it 

use proper conditions

ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, 
myReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: Yes i have declared in manifest file. where i have to use unregisterReceiver()  ?

Comment: If you have declared in manifest file then you have to use component class and use package manager 

    int status = 
    context.getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(component);

now check status if true then disable the receiver or enable it